# SSL breaks a users ability to upload an image

Tags: wordpress, ssl, image-uploading, image-upload

I have a problem that is driving me crazy. I'm working on a business listing website in WordPress which allows business users to upload their businesses, along with a description and an image.

All was working fine in development but as soon as a SSL is installed on the site, image uploads produce an error:

> An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.

The inspector console shows:

> 400 error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

and the file cannot be uploaded.

I'm out of my depth here - any ideas please?

I think this is the relevant part of the theme library - not sure it it helps?

```html
<?php
if ( ! search_and_go_elated_listing_plugin_installed() ) {
 //exit if listing plugin is not installed
 return;
}
if(!function_exists('search_and_go_elated_map_listing_type_settings')) {
    function search_and_go_elated_map_listing_type_settings() {
  
  $meta_box_listing_type = search_and_go_elated_create_meta_box(array(
            'scope' => 'listing-type-item',
            'title' => 'Listing Type Settings',
            'name'  => 'listing_type_settings_meta_box'
        ));
  
  search_and_go_elated_create_meta_box_field(array(
            'name'        => 'eltd_listing_type_show_phone',
            'type'        => 'yesno',
            'label'        =>  esc_html__( 'Show Phone Field', 'search-and-go' ),
   'default_value' => 'yes',
            'parent'      => $meta_box_listing_type
        ));
  
  search_and_go_elated_create_meta_box_field(array(
            'name'        => 'eltd_listing_type_show_website',
            'type'        => 'yesno',
            'label'        =>  esc_html__( 'Show Website Field', 'search-and-go' ),
   'default_value' => 'yes',
            'parent'      => $meta_box_listing_type
        ));

     search_and_go_elated_create_meta_box_field(array(
      'name'        => 'eltd_listing_type_show_email',
      'type'        => 'yesno',
      'label'        =>  esc_html__( 'Show Email Field', 'search-and-go' ),
      'default_value' => 'yes',
      'parent'      => $meta_box_listing_type
     ));
  
  search_and_go_elated_create_meta_box_field(array(
            'name'        => 'eltd_listing_type_show_gallery',
            'type'        => 'yesno',
            'label'        =>  esc_html__( 'Show Gallery Images', 'search-and-go' ),
   'default_value' => 'yes',
            'parent'      => $meta_box_listing_type
        ));
  
  search_and_go_elated_create_meta_box_field(array(
            'name'        => 'eltd_listing_type_show_video',
            'type'        => 'yesno',
            'label'        =>  esc_html__( 'Show Video', 'search-and-go' ),
   'default_value' => 'yes',
            'parent'      => $meta_box_listing_type
        ));

        search_and_go_elated_create_meta_box_field(array(
            'name'        => 'eltd_listing_type_show_audio',
            'type'        => 'yesno',
            'label'        =>  esc_html__( 'Show Audio', 'search-and-go' ),
   'default_value' => 'yes',
            'parent'      => $meta_box_listing_type
        ));
  
  search_and_go_elated_create_meta_box_field(array(
            'name'        => 'eltd_listing_type_show_work_hours',
            'type'        => 'yesno',
            'label'        =>  esc_html__( 'Show Working Hours', 'search-and-go' ),
   'default_value' => 'yes',
            'parent'      => $meta_box_listing_type
        ));
  
  search_and_go_elated_create_meta_box_field(array(
            'name'        => 'eltd_listing_type_show_social_icons',
            'type'        => 'yesno',
            'label'        =>  esc_html__( 'Show Social Icons', 'search-and-go' ),
   'default_value' => 'yes',
            'parent'      => $meta_box_listing_type
        ));
  search_and_go_elated_create_meta_box_field(array(
            'name'        => 'eltd_listing_type_show_price',
            'type'        => 'yesno',
            'label'        =>  esc_html__( 'Show Price', 'search-and-go' ),
   'default_value' => 'yes',
            'parent'      => $meta_box_listing_type
        ));

     search_and_go_elated_create_meta_box_field(array(
      'name'        => 'eltd_listing_type_show_sidebar_gallery',
      'type'        => 'yesno',
      'label'        =>  esc_html__( 'Show Sidebar Gallery', 'search-and-go' ),
      'description' => '',
      'default_value' => 'yes',
      'parent'      => $meta_box_listing_type
     ));

     search_and_go_elated_create_meta_box_field(array(
      'name'        => 'eltd_listing_type_show_booking_form',
      'type'        => 'yesno',
      'label'        =>  esc_html__( 'Show Booking Form', 'search-and-go' ),
      'description' => esc_html__( 'Requires Elated Booking Plugin to be installed', 'search-and-go' ),
      'default_value' => 'yes',
      'parent'      => $meta_box_listing_type
     ));

     //init icon pack hide and show array. It will be populated dinamically from collections array
  $listing_type_icon_pack_hide_array = array();
  $listing_type_icon_pack_show_array = array();

  //do we have some collection added in collections array?
  if (is_array(search_and_go_elated_icon_collections()->iconCollections) && count(search_and_go_elated_icon_collections()->iconCollections)) {

   //get collections params array. It will contain values of 'param' property for each collection
   $listing_type_icon_collections_params = search_and_go_elated_icon_collections()->getIconCollectionsParams();

   //foreach collection generate hide and show array
   foreach (search_and_go_elated_icon_collections()->iconCollections as $dep_collection_key => $dep_collection_object) {
    $listing_type_icon_pack_hide_array[$dep_collection_key] = '';

    //we need to include only current collection in show string as it is the only one that needs to show
    $listing_type_icon_pack_show_array[$dep_collection_key] = '#eltd_listing_type_icon_' . $dep_collection_object->param . '_container';

    //for all collections param generate hide string
    foreach ($listing_type_icon_collections_params as $listing_icon_collections_param) {
     //we don't need to include current one, because it needs to be shown, not hidden
     if ($listing_icon_collections_param !== $dep_collection_object->param) {
      $listing_type_icon_pack_hide_array[$dep_collection_key] .= '#eltd_listing_type_icon_' . $listing_icon_collections_param . '_container,';
     }
    }

    //remove remaining ',' character
    $listing_type_icon_pack_hide_array[$dep_collection_key] = rtrim($listing_type_icon_pack_hide_array[$dep_collection_key], ',');
   }

  }

  search_and_go_elated_create_meta_box_field(

   array(
    'parent' => $meta_box_listing_type,
    'type' => 'select',
    'name' => 'listing_type_icon_pack',
    'default_value' => 'font_awesome',
    'label'  =>  esc_html__( 'Listing Type Icon Pack', 'search-and-go' ),
    'description' => esc_html__( 'Choose icon pack for listing', 'search-and-go' ),
    'options' => search_and_go_elated_icon_collections()->getIconCollections(),
    'args' => array(
     'dependence' => true,
     'hide' => $listing_type_icon_pack_hide_array,
     'show' => $listing_type_icon_pack_show_array
    )
   )

  );

  if (is_array(search_and_go_elated_icon_collections()->iconCollections) && count(search_and_go_elated_icon_collections()->iconCollections)) {

   //foreach icon collection we need to generate separate container that will have dependency set
   //it will have one field inside with icons dropdown
   foreach (search_and_go_elated_icon_collections()->iconCollections as $collection_key => $collection_object) {
    $icons_array = $collection_object->getIconsArray();

    //get icon collection keys (keys from collections array, e.g 'font_awesome', 'font_elegant' etc.)
    $icon_collections_keys = search_and_go_elated_icon_collections()->getIconCollectionsKeys();

    //unset current one, because it doesn't have to be included in dependency that hides icon container
    unset($icon_collections_keys[array_search($collection_key, $icon_collections_keys)]);

    $listing_icon_hide_values = $icon_collections_keys;

    $listing_icon_container = search_and_go_elated_add_admin_container(
     array(
      'parent' => $meta_box_listing_type,
      'name' => 'listing_type_icon_' . $collection_object->param . '_container',
      'hidden_property' => 'listing_type_icon_pack',
      'hidden_value' => '',
      'hidden_values' => $listing_icon_hide_values
     )
    );

    search_and_go_elated_create_meta_box_field(
     array(
      'parent' => $listing_icon_container,
      'type' => 'select',
      'name' => 'listing_type_icon_' . $collection_object->param,
      'default_value' => '',
      'label'  =>  esc_html__( 'Listing Type Icon', 'search-and-go' ),
      'description' => esc_html__( 'Choose Listing Type Icon', 'search-and-go' ),
      'options' => $icons_array,
     )
    );

   }
  }
  
  search_and_go_elated_add_custom_fields_creator(array(
   'name' => 'listing_custom_fields' , 
   'label'  =>  esc_html__( 'Custom Fields Creator', 'search-and-go' ),
   'desciption'  =>  esc_html__( 'Create listing type custom fields', 'search-and-go' ),
   'parent' => $meta_box_listing_type
  ));
  
  $feature_list_title = search_and_go_elated_add_admin_section_title(
    array(
     'parent' => $meta_box_listing_type,
     'title'   =>  esc_html__( 'Listing Type Feature List', 'search-and-go' ),
     'name'  => 'listing_type_feature_list_title'
    )
   );
  
  search_and_go_elated_add_repeater_field(array(
                'name' => 'eltd_listing_type_repeater',
                'parent' => $meta_box_listing_type,
                'fields' => array(
                    array(
                        'type' => 'textsimple',
                        'name' => 'eltd_listing_type_feature_list',
                        'label' => '',
                        'description' => '',
                    ),
                )
            )
        );
  
    }

    add_action('search_and_go_elated_meta_boxes_map', 'search_and_go_elated_map_listing_type_settings');
}
```

Comment: Please update your question and include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you're using to upload images so we can help. Otherwise we won't be able to help out.

Comment: Check the web server logs for a more detailed error message.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure how to find the code that is being used - but I am looking through the many theme files..